# Can OpenGL and Directx totally simulated by software?

Tags: opengl, directx

Some virtual machines do not have displayed card at all. I am wondering OpenGL and DirectX can be simulated by software totally or not?

Comment: 100% possible and 100% impractical.

Comment: @'Krom':: no its not impractical in some cases.  Take virtualized environments using NComputing boxes at schools for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL and DirectX are just APIs. The actual implementation may be done in hardware or software. The OpenGL interface DLL shipped by Windows contains a OpenGL-1.1 software rasterizer. The OpenGL implementation used on Linux, Mesa3D, also contains a software rasterizer fallback, implementing OpenGL-2.1.

Direct3D can be implemented in software emulated as, but normally isn't.

Comment: [VMware Workstation includes experimental support for Direct3D video acceleration. This feature is not fully functional.](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_vidsound_d3d.html)

Comment: May be worth noting that on the Windows platform a program end up using the OpenGL implementation provided by the video board manufacturer, that make full use of the hardware.

Comment: I'd like to add that, although software rasterization of anything else than toy workloads in Direct3D is currently uncommon, we may see a rise of CPU-bound Direct3D in the future through the introduction of [WARP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx) to the Windows runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is yes, and companies like Adobe do just that.
Take a look at SwiftShader:: http://transgaming.com/business/swiftshader

I have to used it before and it runs quite well.